# Did I break phonegap when adjusting environment variables on Windows 7?

Tags: node.js, ant, cordova

1. Installed node.js
2. Installed phonegap: npm install -g phonegap
3. Created the example app: phonegap create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
4. Used the run command to test in Android: phonegap run android

What happened next is it didn't detect the Android SDK, so it asked me for build.phonegap.com account. I went ahead and created an account and entered user/pw and like magic, it created the app in the cloud. I pointed my qr code scanner to the screen and it installed on my Android phone. Cool, but...

I wanted to develop locally using the Android emulator. So I followed the instructions (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide) to install Android SDK, change PATH variables, etc.

When I went back to command line and cd to my phonegap root folder, suddenly "'phonegap' is not recognized as an internal or external command...'. I tried to reinstall phonegap with npm and it looks like it installs just fine again, but even when restarting cmd.exe, phonegap commands do not work.

Any ideas? Changing environment variables shouldn't affect phonegap already installed, right? The only other thing I can think is I had to install Ant and made an ANT_HOME system variable..

Apologies for the noob question. I'm sure I'm just messed up something simple here..

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. I accidentally DELETED the environment variables for node.js when I was trying to APPEND additional environment variables manually for android sdk & Ant. Since phonegap was installed as a node package, it wasn't recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Better reinstall using the [Msysgit](https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/detail?name=msysGit-netinstall-1.8.4-preview20130916.exe&can=2&q=) and give the correct path. In my case envi variable path is as follows,

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\;           ->NodeJS path
F:\windows_adt\sdk\platform-tools;  ->SDK Platform Tools
F:\windows_adt\sdk\tools;           ->SDK Tools
C:\msysgit\bin;                     ->Bin Folder
C:\msysgit\git;                     ->git
C:\msysgit\libexec\git-core;        ->git-core, if you want.
```

To reduce further errors use the recommended msysgit shell.